# test a logical and if FALSE change to TRUE with 10% probability

Tags: r, logical-operators

I'm attempting to evaluate a single (logical) column in a data.frame and wherever there is a FALSE, convert it to TRUE but with 10% probability.  I think the function I need is

```
as.logical(rbinom(1, 1, 0.1))
```

and I would attempt to apply it to the column using lapply but I can not get the syntax of the boolean correct.  For example with the following df

```
df <- data.frame (NM =c("N1", "N2", "N3", NA),
                  D1 = c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,NA),
                  D2 = c(100L,130L,140L,NA),
                  D3 = c(0.5, 1, 0, NA),
                  D4 = c(20, 24, 28, NA),
                  D5 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA)
                  )
```

How would I get R to evaluate each element of df$D1 and when it finds a FALSE, convert it to  TRUE with 10% probability?  FYI this relates to onset of disease with age.  If a person already has disease X then they will continue to have it (T -> T), however each year they have a 10% chance of developing X (F -> T (P=0.1) ) if they don't already have it.

I've attempted with

```
!df$D1
```

but it doesn't work correctly for me.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution. First we get all the row numbers corresponding to `FALSE` in `D1`.

```
(index <- which(!is.na(df$D1) & !df$D1))
## [1] 2
```

There is 1 such a row here.

Then we substitute each such a row with a randomly generated logical value. `TRUE` occurs with probability 0.1 and `FALSE` with `0.9`.

```
df$D1[index] <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), length(index),
                       replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.9))
```

BTW, the code is vectorized: we apply this procedure to all `FALSE`s at once. This can be illustrated by the following:

```
x <- c(TRUE, rep(FALSE, 20), NA) # an exemplary vector
(index <- which(!is.na(x) & !x))
##  [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
x[index] <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), length(index),
                   replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.9))
x
## [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## [18] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE    NA
```